# Google Maps API V3 - Subclass google.maps.Marker: How to call parent methods?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to convert the very useful [LabeledMarker class to Google Maps API V3](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/labeledmarker/). 
I used it in my V2 map... but I want something similar in my V3 map.
I read [Mike's article](http://www.googlemapsbook.com/2007/01/22/extending-gmarker/) about extending GMarker.

I'm trying to do the same with google.maps.Marker, but I'm running into some problems.

Here's my very simple code:

```
function LabeledMarker(opts) { // constructor  
    google.maps.Marker.apply(this, arguments);  
}  

LabeledMarker.prototype = new google.maps.Marker();  

LabeledMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {  
    alert('onAdd1');  
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.onAdd.apply(this, arguments);     
    alert('onAdd2');  
}  

LabeledMarker.prototype.draw = function() {  
    alert('draw1');  
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);  
    alert('draw2');  
}  

LabeledMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {  
    alert('onRemove1');  
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.onRemove.apply(this, arguments);  
    alert('onRemove2');  
}
```

Here's how I call it:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(37, -59);  
var labeledMarker = new LabeledMarker({  
     map: map,  
     position: point,  
     labelText: 'Label'  
});
```

Here's a URL: http://www.canamgroup.ws/GM.nsf/Map2?OpenPage

My Marker is displayed on the map (so I assume that my constructor is successfully calling the `google.maps.Marker` constructor) but my alerts in onAdd, draw and onRemove are never triggered (so I assume that my methods are not successfully calling the `google.maps.Marker` methods).

This is the way Mike was doing it though in V2 (except the method names were different).
I tried:

```
google.maps.Marker.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);  
google.maps.Marker.prototype.draw.apply(this);  
google.maps.Marker.prototype.draw.call(this);  
google.maps.Marker.prototype.draw.call(this, arguments);
```

I'm just beginning to code OO Javascript, so I might be missing something?
Or maybe I have to do something different in V3?
Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: My question should be more "How to override the onAdd(), draw() and onRemove() methods of google.maps.Maker?".  

I did a test with the "setTitle" method and my alert is displayed (and the parent method called):  
LabeledMarker.prototype.setTitle = function(title) {  
    alert('setTitle');  
    google.maps.Marker.prototype.setTitle.apply(this, arguments);  
}  

Does that mean that google.maps.Marker doesn't have onAdd(), draw() and onRemove() methods?  
A Marker is an Overlay, so I thought I could override those methods as well.

Am I trying to do something impossible?
Thanks!